# How to avoid inline onclick attribute for filter selector JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to avoid inline JS edits because the Content Security Header Policy blocks it. My project is similar to the W3 schools filter elements example. Would like to know how to use the JS script without using the onclick attribute.

www. w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_elements

filter.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title> test</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="filter.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Filter DIV Elements</h2>

<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('cars')"> Cars</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('animals')"> Animals</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('fruits')"> Fruits</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('colors')"> Colors</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="column cars">BMW</div>
  <div class="column colors fruits">Orange</div>
  <div class="column cars">Volvo</div>
  <div class="column colors">Red</div>
  <div class="column cars animals">Mustang</div>
  <div class="column colors">Blue</div>
  <div class="column animals">Cat</div>
  <div class="column animals">Dog</div>
  <div class="column fruits">Melon</div>
  <div class="column fruits animals">Kiwi</div>
  <div class="column fruits">Banana</div>
  <div class="column fruits">Lemon</div>
  <div class="column animals">Cow</div>
</div>
<script src="filter_js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

filter.css

```
.column {
  float: left;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

filter_js.js

```
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}


// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

Comment: [Please do not use or link to w3schools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com)

Comment: Hi Jennifer, welcome to stack overflow, In my opinion is quite hard but you can overwrite the dom using elements using something like this `document.getElementById('some_id').removeAttribute("onclick");`, but it is too hacky and you could have some unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thanks! I just decided to do a search bar function instead. Similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470147/how-to-filter-elements-by-name

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) use [`EventTarget.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of the inline handlers. For example:

```js
const btnContainerEl = document.querySelector('#myBtnContainer');
const containerEl = document.querySelector('.container');

btnContainerEl.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    Array.from(containerEl.children).forEach(divEl => {
      if (event.target.value === "all" || divEl.classList.contains(event.target.value)) {
        divEl.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        divEl.style.display = "none";
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<h2>Filter DIV Elements</h2>

<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" value="all"> Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" value="cars"> Cars</button>
  <button class="btn" value="animals"> Animals</button>
  <button class="btn" value="fruits"> Fruits</button>
  <button class="btn" value="colors"> Colors</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="column cars">BMW</div>
  <div class="column colors fruits">Orange</div>
  <div class="column cars">Volvo</div>
  <div class="column colors">Red</div>
  <div class="column cars animals">Mustang</div>
  <div class="column colors">Blue</div>
  <div class="column animals">Cat</div>
  <div class="column animals">Dog</div>
  <div class="column fruits">Melon</div>
  <div class="column fruits animals">Kiwi</div>
  <div class="column fruits">Banana</div>
  <div class="column fruits">Lemon</div>
  <div class="column animals">Cow</div>
</div>
```

Also, I want to point out the use of the [event-delegation technique](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=f7d36cd3db7797edfdc6778f671f309fb703f682-1619634912-0-AUNLWV2nVi8duUmc_i634MDfzC_U_anC6w4T67CaKaFf0BcPmSCeu7_qTwegM4Hkoc1x8ff1EqtbLCauyySVOnmMCG7yos_Th-Dnfqro0Ha1aQ7R_K8acedgEp-Nuz-z6P5H6q0c_E1imjsC0ESKDPcG8xJGSbBNHqYYBnadUA35SzPIMz3eaAxo-JLe0T_I9w23O9lj3lCVMNerwMOz4ESriQ9Z9fwcWSl-98aks5jlYPd8RPnnBpxI0vcCNsHUwF_DfqODwIGcGvGHsJxmbpmNSpgm7s-PvBboBneJ759qXXXAF9xIiOtn82uMS_fMJt-E6H-li_eEWBjxHymNQLf8O23G2u2_BrNYwZ2_atNLzRckEiAThZT6wuOVLXpLhJONBhpd-eB7Q-1VUSV67Rg) (i.e., putting the event listener on a parent element instead of every single individual button) which is more efficient than many listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, but it works. The function filterSelection() just handles the hiding/showing of "column" elements.

In the eventlistener for btnContainer I can get the type by the name of the button.

```js
var filterSelection = type => {
  var current = document.querySelectorAll('.show');
  current.forEach(elm => elm.classList.remove('show'));
  if (type === 'all') type = 'column';
  var elmToShow = document.querySelectorAll(`.${type}`);
  elmToShow.forEach(elm => elm.classList.add('show'));
};


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
  
  btnContainer.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON') {
      buttons.forEach(elm => {elm.classList.remove('active')});
      e.target.classList.add('active');
      var type = e.target.name;
      filterSelection(type);
    }
  });

  filterSelection("all")
});
```

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the buttons */

.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> test</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="filter.css" />
  <script src="filter_js.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Filter DIV Elements</h2>

  <div id="myBtnContainer">
    <button class="btn active" name="all"> Show all</button>
    <button class="btn" name="cars"> Cars</button>
    <button class="btn" name="animals"> Animals</button>
    <button class="btn" name="fruits"> Fruits</button>
    <button class="btn" name="colors"> Colors</button>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="column cars">BMW</div>
    <div class="column colors fruits">Orange</div>
    <div class="column cars">Volvo</div>
    <div class="column colors">Red</div>
    <div class="column cars animals">Mustang</div>
    <div class="column colors">Blue</div>
    <div class="column animals">Cat</div>
    <div class="column animals">Dog</div>
    <div class="column fruits">Melon</div>
    <div class="column fruits animals">Kiwi</div>
    <div class="column fruits">Banana</div>
    <div class="column fruits">Lemon</div>
    <div class="column animals">Cow</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

test
    
    
     -->

```
<style>
    .column {
        float: left;
        background-color: #2196F3;
        color: #ffffff;
        width: 100px;
        line-height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 2px;
        /* display: none; */
    }
    
    .filters {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .show {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .container {
        margin-top: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    /* Style the buttons */
    
    .btn {
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .btn:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
    
    .btn.active {
        background-color: #2196F3;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
```

```
<h2>Filter DIV Elements</h2>

<div class="filterSection">
    <div id="myBtnContainer">
        <button class="btn active" data-id="all"> Show all</button>
        <button class="btn" data-id="cars"> Cars</button>
        <button class="btn" data-id="animals"> Animals</button>
        <button class="btn" data-id="fruits"> Fruits</button>
        <button class="btn" data-id="colors"> Colors</button>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="filters show" id="cars">
            <div class="column">BMW</div>
            <div class="column">Volvo</div>
            <div class="column">Mustang</div>
        </div>

        <div class="filters" id="colors">
            <div class="column">Red</div>
            <div class="column">Orange</div>
            <div class="column">blue</div>

        </div>
        <div class="filters" id="animals">
            <div class="column">Mustang</div>
            <div class="column">Cat</div>
            <div class="column">Dog</div>
            <div class="column">Kiwi</div>
            <div class="column animals">Cow</div>
        </div>
        <div class="filters" id="fruits">
            <div class="column">Melon</div>
            <div class="column">Banana</div>
            <div class="column">Lemon</div>
            <div class="column">Kiwi</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>





        const section = document.querySelector(".filterSection");
    const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll(".filters");
    rows.forEach(row => {
        row.classList.add('show');
    })
    section.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.dataset.id);
        const id = e.target.dataset.id;
        if (id) {
            btns.forEach((btn) => {
                btn.classList.remove("active");
                e.target.classList.add("active");
            });
            rows.forEach((row) => {
                row.classList.remove("show");
            });
            if (id == 'all') {
                // rows.style.display = 'block';
                rows.forEach(row => {
                    row.classList.add('show');
                })
            } else {
                const element = document.getElementById(id);
                element.classList.add("show");
                console.log(element);
            }


        }
    });
```